# Dynamically add column with today's date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-columns

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will dynamically add a column with today's date every day. The reason for this is because each day I get a new file with a new count for each item. They want to keep a running historical total by day. This is the only way I can think I can do this, unless one of you has a suggestion for this schema design. Thank you.

Comment: `insert into table values (col1, col2, getdate())` ? Need more details from you.

Comment: Why not just adding a row each day having a date as one column and running total as another?

Comment: You could probably do it with a normalized table and a pivot query

Comment: Ok, my schema currently is like this:

CVEId PK INT Not Null, 09-19-2016 INT Not Null

How do I get it to add another column with the next date? Or is the running total and date column the best way? I am trying to correlate by CVEId without having to repeat the same CVEId over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is Your Query:**

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[usp_AddCollumByDate]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE usp_AddCollumByDate
GO

create procedure usp_AddCollumByDate
as
begin
    declare @sql varchar(max);
    declare @toDay varchar(20)=CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112);
    set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD  D' +  @toDay + ' varchar(max); '
    print @sql
    EXECUTE(@sql);
end

exec usp_AddCollumByDate
```

It will add column every day (for today's example its add):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD  D20160920 varchar(max);
```

**Now Listen Carefully:**

1. I have add a Letter `D` in front of today's date. It is because
   `20160920` is a `INVALID` column name. You have to start a column
   with a letter(for example An3, a33...)
2. I have used the style `112` which give the date as `yyyymmdd`, You
   can not use `11`,`111`,`10` and some other style because its give the date
   with `-` like `mm-dd-yyyy` and it is an `INVALID` column name. You
   Can not use `-` in a column name.[`Here is more style`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) , Try to
   use `yyyymmdd`,`yymmdd` style